# hybrid interpreted compiled language

Tags: programming, language

Are there any languages that give the option of being used in interpreted mode or compiled into machine code?

So when I want it to work on any device it can but when I want it to run really well on one specific device without installing an interpreter I can tweak it and benefit from native performance.

Comment: Sure, but this is only one small part of language selection. What else do you need? What paradigms do you code in? How "interpreted" is interpreted? How much of a performance speedup are you looking for in compilation? What specialty are you going to be using the language for -- numeric processing, websites, databases, communications, real-time processing, financial data?

Comment: I think that this would have been better asked at http://stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Mawg: This would be off-topic at stackexchange. The question is very vague and broad but the best place to ask it is probably here.

Comment: Aaargh!! I meant Programmers - oops

Answer (score 2):

[JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) is such a language.

JavaScript can interpreted. Actually that was the most usual case until a few years ago.

JavaScript can also be compiled and run natively. This is what [V8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript_engine%29) does for instance.

Comment: I believe V8 compiles and then runs at runtime. I'm looking for something like Java that also allows me to pre-compile like C++.